# How to retrieve limited records if the user is not logged in and all records if the user is logged in in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes, authorization, middleware, laravel-sanctum

I have a Laravel route that I want to handle differently depending on whether the user is logged in or not. If the user is not logged in, I want to retrieve only 5 records (limit 5) in the controller. If the user is logged in, I want to retrieve all the records.

Here is my current route:

```
Route::get('/test', 'TestApiController@index');
```

When I set middleware('auth:sanctum') for my Route, the response will be 401 Unauthorized, but I want to get limited records for this situation instead. How can I modify the route and the controller to achieve this? Also, how do I check if the user is logged in?

Here is my current controller code:

```
class TestApiController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            $data = Test::all();
        } else {
            $data = Test::limit(5)->get();
        }
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

I think I need to get the authentication parameter from the request header to check if the user is logged in:

```
$request->header('Authorization')
```

How can I modify my code to achieve the desired functionality? Thank you.

I try when or middlewareIf and middleware(function ($request, $next),

but they are not working..

Comment: auth()->check() should work and your code seems right and you don't have to use auth middleware since auth()->check() will return false for not logged in users. Can you tell if you're using jwt or api tokens?

Comment: Is is a stateless API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that your code is authorized by **Sanctum**

Route:

```
//Note: Without middleware('auth:sanctum')
Route::get('/test', 'TestApiController@index');
```

Controller:

Solution #1:

```
class TestApiController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $token = $request->bearerToken();
        $personalAccessToken = \Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken::findToken($token);

       if( $personalAccessToken ) {
              // 'logged in'
              // Access to user information
              // $user = $personalAccessToken->tokenable;

               $data = Test::all();
           } else {
               // 'Not logged in'
               $data = Test::limit(5)->get();
        }
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

Solution #2:

```
class TestApiController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if (\Auth::guard('sanctum')->check()) {
            // 'logged in'
            $data = Test::all();
        } else {
            // 'Not logged in'
            $data = Test::limit(5)->get();
        }
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixing some concepts there.

Your route looks like an API route, which uses 'api' guard instead of web. When you call for `auth()->check()` its getting the 'web' guard.

Knowing this, your controller should look like this:

```
class TestApiController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if (auth('api')->check()) {
            $data = Test::all();
        } else {
            $data = Test::limit(5)->get();
        }
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

You can read more in the [Laravel authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#introduction) documentation.

Comment: You can also call the guard using the static method: 'Auth::guard('api')->check()'